# Why Linear Regression through origin does not go through center of mass point?

Tags: statistical-inference, linear-regression

Imagine $X$ is a sample and we have a model $y = \alpha + \beta x$. We know that points $(x_1, ... ,x_n)$ from $X$ do not necessarily satisfy the equation, so we include $\epsilon _i$ error terms.
Now we have better model $y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon$. We want to minimize the sum of the squared error terms, so we solve the following minimization problem:

$$
\min_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \epsilon_i^2 =\min_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \alpha -\beta x_i)^2
$$

We call $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ the solutions of the above optimization problem and now we have the best fitting model in terms of ordinary least square method.

I could not solve this minimization problem myself, but I will believe the derivation from [the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) Wikipedia article.

It is obvious that the center of mass point $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ passes through the model line.

Now, it's time for another of my stupid questions: If we know that in the true model, $Y=0$, when $X=0$ (i.e. intercept term is zero), isn't it very easy to create the model by just connecting the origin $(0,0)$ with $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$?

Comment: You certainly can "create the model by just connecting the origin $(0,0)$ with $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$" but this will usually not "minimize the sum of the squared error terms" in this case.  Try it in a simple case, such as the points $(1,1)$ and $(3,5)$ and compare the sum of squares of residuals from $\hat y=\frac32 x$ which passes through the mean point $(2,3)$ and from $\hat y=\frac85 x$ which does not

Comment: @angryavian $\hat \beta = \frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2} \not = \frac{\sum y_i}{\sum x_i} =\frac{\bar y}{\bar x}$ here if you want to minimise the sum of squares of residuals.

Comment: @Henry thank you. So it's just that the solutions for the optimization problems in two cases are different, therefore in one case the center mass point passes through the model line, and in the other case it does not. I will try to understand the derivation of the solution to the optimization problem better and expand my answer, if I understand

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the correction, that was a very silly mistake of me.